# How to find object tag with param, and embed tag inside HTML using simple html DOM php

Tags: php, html

I found it really hard for me to understand the simple html dom of php. Even if I read the instruction on how to do it. As for me, I'm just new in programming industry. As I've been searching on how to find the object tag and embed, I can't find the right answer. So in here , I will post my problem and hoping for the right answer. :)

I can't find the object of this: http://vodlocker.com/embed-gu09418zgs6y.html

and here is the object tag with param from the page source of the vodlocker. and this is what i want to get.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://vodlocker.com/player/player.swf" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#000000" id="flvplayer" name="flvplayer" tabindex="0" __idm_id__="937985">
   <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
   <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true">
   <param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="flashvars" value="netstreambasepath=http%3A%2F%2Fvodlocker.com%2Fembed-gu09418zgs6y.html&amp;id=flvplayer&amp;file=http%3A%2F%2F95.211.193.83%3A8777%2Fk6ceg4duoo4pcnokaktshz6a5e6vcg4hy7lzvwxjtd7dcwtb4o6vtdk5fe%2Fv.mp4&amp;provider=http&amp;image=http%3A%2F%2F95.211.193.83%3A8777%2Fi%2F02%2F00142%2Falirtn87xlws.jpg&amp;skin=http%3A%2F%2Fvodlocker.com%2Fplayer%2Fmodieus1.zip&amp;duration=12126&amp;plugins=timeslidertooltipplugin-3h%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Flp.longtailvideo.com%2F5%2Fsharing%2Fsharing.swf&amp;allowfullscreen=always&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;allowscriptaccess=always&amp;stretching=uniform&amp;abouttext=vodLocker&amp;aboutlink=http%3A%2F%2FvodLocker.com&amp;timeslidertooltipplugin.preview=%5B%5BJSON%5D%5D%7B%22enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22path%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2F95.211.193.83%3A8777%2Fi%2F02%2F00142%2F%22%2C%22prefix%22%3A%22alirtn87xlws%22%2C%22frequency%22%3A%22485%22%7D&amp;timeslidertooltipplugin.pluginmode=HYBRID&amp;sharing.sharing.link=&amp;sharing.sharing.code=%253CIFRAME%2520SRC%253D%2522http%253A%252F%252Fvodlocker.com%252Fembed-gu09418zgs6y-720x400.html%2522%2520FRAMEBORDER%253D0%2520MARGINWIDTH%253D0%2520MARGINHEIGHT%253D0%2520SCROLLING%253DNO%2520WIDTH%253D720%2520HEIGHT%253D%253E%253C%252FIFRAME%253E&amp;sharing.link=http%3A%2F%2Fvodlocker.com%2Fgu09418zgs6y&amp;sharing.code=%253CIFRAME%2520SRC%253D%2522http%253A%252F%252Fvodlocker.com%252Fembed-gu09418zgs6y-640x360.html%2522%2520FRAMEBORDER%253D0%2520MARGINWIDTH%253D0%2520MARGINHEIGHT%253D0%2520SCROLLING%253DNO%2520WIDTH%253D640%2520HEIGHT%253D360%253E%253C%252FIFRAME%253E&amp;sharing.pluginmode=HYBRID&amp;controlbar.position=over&amp;dock.position=left&amp;logo.file=http%3A%2F%2Fvodlocker.com%2Fimages%2Fvodjw_logo.png&amp;logo.hide=false&amp;logo.timeout=10&amp;logo.over=1&amp;logo.out=0.8&amp;logo.position=top-right&amp;logo.link=http%3A%2F%2FVodlocker.com">
</object>
```

Here's my code. which is not working. i dont know why. also on other sites that contains embed. it is also not working.

```
include "include/simple_html_dom.php";
$a = "http://vodlocker.com/embed-gu09418zgs6y.html";
$html = file_get_html($a);
$b = $html->find('object')[0];
echo $b;
```

Comment: Can you explain 'not working'? ("I'm expecting *x* but it does *y*...")

Comment: @KristenJukowski It's not displaying any echo from $b. Have you tried it? is it working on you? maybe i got an error somewhere. Oh my, this is hard for me.

Comment: Sure, just tried it - see my answer below. If you're trying to grab the video url, you're looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems, it looks like.  First off, I believe what you want is:

```
$b = $html->find('object', 0);
```

Per the docs, this is how to find the first instance of the `<object>` tag.

Your second problem, though, is that the $html does not return any code with `<object>` tags - the code block you're searching for is not there.

If what you're looking for is the `http://95.211.193.83:8777/k6ceg4duoo4pcnokaktshz6a5e6vcg4hy7lzvwxjtd7ddxdeooarqi7uci/v.mp4` value, it's embedded in the `<script>` tags in the header, so try:

```
$b = $html->find('script');
```

Then loop through the array that `$b` returns until you get what you're looking for.

Comment: ok i'll try that. so if the code that i'm searching is blocked, it will become error? right?

Comment: http://95.211.193.83:8777/k6ceg4duoo4pcnokaktshz6a5e6vcg4hy7lzvwxjtd7ddxdeooarqi7uci/v.mp4  -- i tried. this. it says wrong I.P. i've tried copying the object tag until the end of the object tag. and paste on some php file and run it. it is working. that's what im trying to get.

Comment: I think you are right. it is blocked. when i inspect the element. i could the see the object tag. but when i view the page source. i can't find the object tag.

Comment: Where are you seeing the <object> tags? When I look at the html on the link you provided, there is no object tags anywhere - http://vodlocker.com/embed-gu09418zgs6y.html"

Comment: Yeah, well that makes sense. Simple HTML DOM is going to see exactly what you see when you "view source" in your browser.  I was actually able to download the mp4 file, for the record.

Comment: They got nice security on their html codes. This will be hard for me. Thanks for the information. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is `$b = $html->find('object')[0];`. Although that works in many languages it won't work on PHP versions below 5.4. Do this instead:

```
$b = $html->find('object'); $b = $b[0];
```

Personally I use DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://vodlocker.com/embed-gu09418zgs6y.html');
if($objs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('object')){
  foreach($objs as $o){
    // $o is each <object> $objectHTML[] = $dom->saveHTML($o);
    foreach($o->childNodes as $p){
      if(preg_match('/^param$/i', $p->nodeName)){
        // $p is each <param> in loop
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where I have commented out `$objectHTML[] = $dom->saveHTML($o);`, the `$objectHTML` Array would contain each Object as HTML. `$objectHTML[0]` would be the first object tag and its contents as HTML.

Comment: is the DOMdocument will gonna use any plugins or anything?

Comment: DOMDocument is standard as of PHP5+. Do you want the `textContent` or what exactly do you need?

Comment: i have a PHP Version 5.4.22 sir.   should i simply copy your code and change some of it. and it will work?

Comment: What do you want? The entire `<object>` tag and its contents as HTML? Just some attributes? Just some text? I really don't know, what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: entire object tag sir. but i happen to realize that the vodlocker is blocking their real html codes. when i inspect the elements using chrome, i can find the object tag. but when view page source. the object tag is not there..

Comment: Is there way to download the video when extracting the object tag?

Comment: From a web development standpoint that would happen on the Client side. You can have an HTML link to the download or use JavaScript, or use `header('LOCATION: videosrc.mp4');` or the like in PHP. At the end of the day your Browser decides what to do with a file. Usually, the default behavior is to download any file that it doesn't automatically execute. Of course HTML or HTML generated by a PHP will not automatically attempt to download. You don't even have to keep their video on your Server if you use just use their Server through the object data attribute or the video src property.