# How to grab flash video and download video data with file_get_contents using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, flash, dom

I am simply looking to screen scrape a web page that contains flash videos. While scraping the web page utilizing [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) I like to grab the embed snippet and download the video data. Can anyone help?

Reference to possibly help:
[How to find object tag with param and embed tag inside html using simple html d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414146/how-to-find-object-tag-with-param-and-embed-tag-inside-html-using-simple-html-d#answer-20414326)

Comment: Download or display it on your website?

Comment: I would like to "download" the video.

Comment: Once I download the data the video data, I'm going to save it to a database.

Comment: You can use this service http://savedeo.com/en for downloading videos. They have API too.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's an universal solution, otherwise youtube-dl's [special-casing](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html) for many sites wouldn't be necessary.
If the site you have in mind is on that list I would recommend simply using youtube-dl.

Comment: Yes, it's on the list. Thank you for that. Never worked with Python before. Is it possible to provide a PHP script video download data example while using Python?

Comment: you can just call it as command line application, via `system()` or similar

Answer (score 0):

If you`re using linux server, you can use this small PHP wrapper for youtube-dl. Just pass url of the page with video to the function.

```
function video_download($video_url) {
    $downloaderUrl = 'https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2015.01.23.4/youtube-dl';
    $downloaderPath = '/tmp/youtube-dl';
    $videoPath = '/tmp/videos';

    if(!file_exists($videoPath.'/')) {
        mkdir($videoPath, 0777);
    }
    if(!file_exists($downloaderPath)) {
        file_put_contents($downloaderPath, file_get_contents($downloaderUrl));
        chmod($downloaderPath, 0777);
    }

    exec($downloaderPath.' -o "'.$videoPath.'/%(title)s.%(ext)s":w '.$video_url);
    return true;
}
```

Usage example:

```
video_download('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0');
```

If you interested in some explanation, it`s just grab youtube-dl downloader from website, save it to your tmp folder and then run it with url passed. Result is saved to the other folder in tmp.

Comment: I'll test it tonight and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: Tested it... Not working? I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Do you check /tmp/videos folder after running? It should contain downloaded videos.

Comment: Yes. I don't see anything there? Any suggestions?

Comment: There is not enough information to determine precisely. May be you trying to grab video from website that doesn`t supported by youtube-dl